# Python: Reason for the name parameter when defining a type or named tuple

Tags: python, tuples, namedtuple

I'm still new to Python, so this may be a dumb question, but I don't understand the purpose of the first parameter to `type()` and `namedtuple()`:

```
tuple_typename = namedtuple( 'tuple_typename', 'member1 member2 member3' )

custom_typename = type( 'custom_typename', (base_type,), members_dictionary )
```

I don't understand the difference between the return value and the string parameter? If the return value is a type reference, why do we need to specify it as a parameter? Or if we need to specify it as a string parameter, why do we need to capture the return value?

And one other related question: If the input string is a type-name specification, is there any way to control the namespace that type-name will be added to? For example, can I add a sub-class to an existing class from outside of that class?

**Edit:** Even though I accepted a good answer, I was wondering if anyone could clear one other thing up. Once I define a named tuple or custom type, when and/or where would I make use of the first string parameter? How can I reference the type-name later on using the name I specified for that parameter? Is that possible? Or is the type-reference lost once the function return value falls out of scope?
**Update:** See comments of accepted answer

Comment: The string is simply the name of the new type. It becomes the type's `__name__` attribute. That's all it's for. It is not added to any namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Name" is an overloaded term in Python. When some refers to the "name of a type", it could be one of two things:

1. The "inherent" name, which is part of the definition of the type itself and accessible via its `__name__` attribute.
2. The name of a variable which *refers* to the type. There can be multiple variables that reference the same type, and none of these names are accessible from the type itself.

For example:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> x = A
>>> del A
>>> y = x
>>> A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
>>> x.__name__
'A'
>>> y.__name__
'A'
```

The `class` statement sets both types of names: the identifier following the `class` keyword is used both to set the inherent name of the type (by using it as the first argument to the call to `type`) *and* to create a new variable that refers to the type. That variable, like any other, can be unset using `del`, but as long as *other* names still refer to the type, it is not lost. You can see the inherent name via either of the two extant references to type `A`.

Comment: This is really useful information. I didn't realize Python type referencing worked this way. However, I'm still wondering if the first parameter of `type()` and `namedtuple()` has any meaning beyond human identification (debugging/printing)? I edited the question to include this, even though I've already accepted this answer. Is there any way to access the type-reference once the return value of those functions falls out of scope?

Comment: The inherent name is mostly, if not entirely, for debugging. It's legal, for example, to have two types with the same name (Given `A = type("A", (object,),{})` and `B = type("A", (A,), {})`, `A` and `B` refer to distinct types.) I'm not sure I understand the last question. Names have scopes, not values, so even if one name goes out of scope, the object is still available via in-scope names. Once *all* names have gone out of scope (and so the object's reference count drops to 0), the object is garbage collected.

Comment: What I meant by the last question was simply: Is there any way to reference the type if I don't record the return value. I was wondering if the input type-name is in some way recorded and accessible after the function is called. Eg, if I just call `type( 'my_type',...)` without recording return value, would I be able to do something like `my_type()` later on? Thank you for clarifying and providing so much detailed information. BTW, I think `namedtuple()` does complain if you try to define two with the same name. Or at least I read that somewhere.

Comment: No, because you never saved a reference to the type in the first place. As soon as `type` returns, the reference count of the returned object goes to 0.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it now. Really appreciate your knowledge and patience

Answer (score 1):

The `typename` is the *name* of the *type* of the namedtuple. So, if you would surround the tuple with the `type()` built-in function you would see the `typename` parameter.

```
from collections import namedtuple

RGB = namedtuple('Colors', ['red', 'blue', 'green'])

print(RGB)  # PRINTS: <class '__main__.Colors'>
```

You can use indexing or attribute names to get the values, like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# initialize new 'namedtuple' object
RGB = namedtuple('Colors', ['red', 'blue', 'green'])

# initialize new objects of type 'RGB'
tuple1 = RGB(5, 64, 32)

print(tuple1.red)
print(tuple1.blue)
print(tuple1[-1]) # gets the last value --> green
```

Comment: I edited the second example to make it clearer, but I had to change some things. You can check the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58356239/revisions) and revert anything you don't like.

Comment: Really neat. Are named tuples as efficient as classes? Not relevant to the topic, I know. I will leave it at that. I noticed you are not using the type-name "Colors" anywhere after defining the type. Would there ever be a reason to reference that type-name after defining it?

Comment: Thanks to chepner, I now know the answer to my (second) question above is no.